# Find simultaneous multiple "Text" options in HTML

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use a simple syntax for finding several posible options for a text within a tag.

Let's say I have the following code:

```
multi= soup.find("h3", text="Experience").replace_with(code)
```

I would like to find `text = "Experience"` or `"Summary"`.

I tried:

```
multi= soup.find("h3", {text:["Experience",'Summary']}).replace_with(code)
```

But did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression

```
import re
soup.find(text=re.compile('Experience|Summary')).replace_with(code)
```